# Sign of Ramanujan $\tau$ function

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

The Ramanujan $\tau(n)$ seemed to have random positive/negative signs:

```
    n            1     2     3     4     5      6       7        8      ...
    tau(n)       1    -24    252   -1472  4830  −6048   −16744   84480  ...
```

Is there a closed-form formula for the sign of $\tau(n)$?

By closed-form formula for $sign(\tau(n))$, I meant something like (1) if $n=2 mod(263)$, then $sign(\tau(n))>0$; (2)  if $n=3 mod(p)$ and $p$ is any prime, then $sign(\tau(n))<0$;  If $n=12398888$, an arbitrary number, then $sign(\tau(n))>0$ etc.

Or simply put: For a given number $n$, what is the sign of $\tau(n)$, 1,-1, or 0?

Thanks-
mike

EDIT:
$\tau(mn)=\tau(m)\tau(n)$ whenever $(m,n)=1$ (Thanks to Peter Humphries!), If $n=p_1^{r_1}\cdots p_m^{r_m}$ where $p_1,...,p_m$ are prime factors, then $sign(\tau(n))=(sign(\tau(p_1^{r_1}))\cdots (sign(\tau(p_m^{r_m}))$.

So the problem is reduced to find the formula for $sign(\tau(p^r)$ where $p$ is any prime number and $r$ is any positive number.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a closed-form formula? Isn't $\text{sign}(\tau(n))$ a closed-form formula?

Comment: Perhaps a "useful" closed form formula was meant. Oy.

Comment: @BrunoJoyal. By closed-form formula for $sign(\tau(n))$, I meant something like (1) if $n=2 mod(263)$, then $sign(\tau(n))>0$; (2)  if $n=3 mod(p)$ and $p$ is any prime, then $sign(\tau(n))<0$;  If $n=12398888$, an arbitrary number, then $sign(\tau(n))>0$ etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm quite certain there's no closed form for the sign of $\tau(n)$, but the behaviour of the sign of $\tau(n)$ is covered in some detail in [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2008-45-02/S0273-0979-08-01207-X/home.html) of Barry Mazur, and explained in [some more detail](http://publications.ias.edu/sarnak/paper/497) by Peter Sarnak.

EDIT: Your statement about the multiplicativity of $\tau(n)$ is incorrect. The function $\tau(n)$ is multiplicative but not completely multiplicative, which is to say that $\tau(mn) = \tau(m) \tau(n)$ holds whenever $(m,n) = 1$ (that is, whenever $m$ and $n$ are coprime), but not in general.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. Since $\tau(mn)=\tau(m)\tau(n)$, if $n=p_1^{r_1}\cdots p_m^{r_m}$ where $p_1,...,p_m$ are prime factors, then $sign(\tau(n))=(sign(\tau(p_1))^{r_1}\cdots (sign(\tau(p_m))^{r_m}$